# coverage report post step not picking up data in previous step

Tags: python, jenkins, build, pytest, coverage.py

I have a `post` `always` step in `Jenkinsfile` that runs `coverage report -m`.  The reason why it's in the post step is I want coverage report, regardless even if tests fail.  I see that it's running but it's not picking up data from the test phase: `python3 -m coverage run -m pytest -v tests`

In `Jenkinsfile`, I have:

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        dir('src') {
            sh "python3 -m coverage run -m pytest -v tests"
        }   
    }

    post {
        always {
            sh "python3 -m coverage report -m"
        }
    }
}
```

`coverage report -m` reports that there's no data: `No data to report`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I needed to run `coverage report -m` in the same directory as the one I ran for tests.

```
stage('Test') {
    steps {
        dir('src') {
            sh "python3 -m coverage run -m pytest -v tests"
        }   
    }

    post {
        always {
            dir('src') {
                sh "python3 -m coverage report -m"
            }
        }
    }
}
```